# wso2 api manager GW 101504 error Connection timed out (no input was detected on this connection) that leads to SUSPENDED state of wso2 after recall

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

if you call an API with header being set to application/json and body sent null.below is curl request :

```
 curl --location 
 'https://10.10.20.10:8243/api/test/v1/test
 --header 'Id: 100' \
--header 'channel: WEB' \
--header 'code: 0011111111' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: cookiesession1=2A041602JFUID8V8GGVYYBDQG3XTF11A' \
--data ''
```

the API gateway waits a default time for an Input and if no input was detected connection over the maximum period of inactivity returns 101504 error code.if you send a request another time is will be suspended and It is a big issue for our use case , how to check if body was empty at once send appropriate error?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the following property for the API? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-reference/http-transport-properties/#force_post_put_nobody. This will accept requests even when there is no any payload mentioned in the Request for both POST and PUT methods.

Comment: thanx for your reply @Athiththan..does it implemented in wso2 api manager 3.2.0?

Comment: Yes, it is available in most of the WSO2 API Manager versions (from 2.5 onwards)

Comment: @Athiththan I want to add this property globally, does it work if I add this property in fault.xml file ?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue you are facing by adding this to the respective API?

Comment: @Athiththan this problem solved with adding this property in fault.xml , but it takes to 2 minute to respond , what is the reason?

Comment: When you invoke the Backend directly, are you observing these delays? Please check whether you are experiencing these delays with the direct backend calls. If not, then it is good to enable more logs and identify the issue in your environment. This property will not add any latency to the existing API Requests, this will just allow the API Manager Gateway to pass the POST and PUT requests that are invoked without any Body. I'll post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour might be because the WSO2 API Manager Gateway is expecting a Request Payload in the POST or PUT Request.

You can follow this [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-reference/http-transport-properties/#force_post_put_nobody) to disable this behaviour. The `FORCE_POST_PUT_NOBODY` synapse property can configure the API Manager not to wait for any Request Payloads when a PUT or POST Request is made without any payload.